# PHP for loop not working as intended

Tags: php, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I was using if statements to check if a custom field exists and if it does, to output some HTML. Since the number of fields was getting bigger I used a loop and it worked on one website:

```
                   <?php 
                    for( $iteration = 1; $iteration <= 20; $iteration++){ 

                      if ( get_field("imagen".$iteration ) ){ ?>
                            <div class="slider-item"> 
                              <img src="<?php echo get_field("imagen".$iteration)['url'] ?>" alt="slider photo" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
```

I'm now trying to do the same on a second website but it doesn't work at all, the full code is this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title">', '</h2>' ); ?>
        <p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div id="slider-constructora" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">

                    <?php 
                        for( $iteration = 1; $iteration <= 100; $iteration++){ 
                          if ( get_field("img-".$iteration ) ){ ?>
                            <li><img src="<?php echo get_field("img-".$iteration)['url'] ?>" class="img-responsive"></li> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>

        </ul>
    </div><!-- slider -->

    <div id="carousel-constructora" class="flexsilder">
        <ul class="slides">

                    <?php 
                        for( $iteration = 1; $iteration <= 100; $iteration++){ 
                          if ( get_field("img-".$iteration ) ){ ?>
                            <li><img src="<?php echo get_field("img-".$iteration)['url'] ?>" class="img-responsive"></li> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>

        </ul>

    </div><!-- carousel -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Is there something wrong in there? The field names are correct.

Comment: Looks fine. Are you certain that an array is returned by get_field(), though? what does `var_export(get_field("img-".$iteration));` look like? What exactly is happening, are you getting crashes or is it just not outputting at all / not outputting what you expected?

Comment: I just get a blank section where the li's and the images should be. Thing is, if I use what I had before the loop, it works fine, and it's this: <?php if( get_field("img-1") ): ?>
    <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo get_field("img-1")['url']; ?>"></li>
   <?php endif; ?> which is basically the same and like i said I'm using the same loop on another page and it does work so I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Have you considered just using a repeater field in ACF?

Comment: I don't have ACF Pro.